# Clear form after form post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to do something a little bit tricky.

I am trying to clear my form, inputs especially after I've submitted the form. Whatever, when I am trying to do so. The form clears but the post never executes. I want it do do both, why it is a little tricky is since I am using  so I don't have to reload the page after the form post.

```
<script>
function submitForm() {
  $('form[name="cform"]').submit();
  $('input[type="text"], textarea').val('');
  return;
}
</script>

            <iframe name="target" style="display:none;"></iframe>
            <form name="cform" target="target" action="steamauth/chat.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" maxlength="120" name="message" style="margin-top: 1vh; margin-left: 2vh; width: 64%">
            <button type="submit" name="chat" onclick="submitForm()" style="background-color: #212223; border-radius: 4px; color: black;  border: 0px solid #4CAF50; width: 20%; height: 28px;"><font color="white">Send</font></button>
            </form>
```

Is there even a solution?

Comment: Please comment on what you believe.

Comment: where's the php for this?

Comment: you need to use ajax btw.

Comment: too many unclosed questions btw.

Comment: the PHP don't matter, since the page is not refreshing when I click button "Send" as there is an iframe there.

Comment: Maybe in an olschool way, onclick="submitForm(); document.querySelector('#cform').reset();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `submit()` on its own simply submits the form as if the submit button was pressed with no JS present. Additionally, you'll need to use AJAX for what you're after. Try something like this (adapted from the example on https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):

```
<script>
    $('form[name="cform"]').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $( this ),
            data = $form.serialize(),
            url = $form.attr( "action" );

        var posting = $.post( url, data );

        posting.done(function( data ) {
            $('input[type="text"], textarea').val('');
        });
    });
</script>

<iframe name="target" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<form name="cform" target="target" action="steamauth/chat.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" maxlength="120" name="message" style="margin-top: 1vh; margin-left: 2vh; width: 64%">
    <button type="submit" name="chat" style="background-color: #212223; border-radius: 4px; color: black;  border: 0px solid #4CAF50; width: 20%; height: 28px;"><font color="white">Send</font></button>
</form>
```

You'll need to further modify to take into account things like submission failures, but that should get you moving in the right direction. I recommend reading through the documentation at the link listed above for more info on callbacks (e.g. `.done()` in code above).

Answer (score 0):

`submitForm()` must return `true` in order to have the form actually submit.

Answer (score 0):

MKM's answer is correct. To clear all input types on a page, use this instead of $('input[type="text"],textarea').val();
This example clears all inputs in three forms. Tested except for select-multiple.

```
$(':input','#Form1','#Form2','#Form3').each(function()
{
    switch(this.type)
    {
        case "text":
        case "textarea":
        case "hidden":
        {
           this.value = ''; break;
        }
        case "radio":
        case "checkbox":
        {
            this.checked=false; break;
        }
        case "select-one":
        {
            // Set dropdowns to default value
            $(this).prop("selectedIndex", 0); break;
        }
        case "select-multiple":
        {
            $(this).prop("selectedIndex", 0); break;
        } 
        case "file":
        {
            $(this).value = ""; break;
        }
    }
});
```